# Show whitespace when dealing with regexps

Tags: feature-request, source-code, whitespace

When answering question about regexps, it would be great if whitespace could be shown in the code listing. Whitespace plays a crucial role and it's easy to miss and get it wrong.

What I'm looking for is something resembling `verbatim*` in LaTeX:

```
\begin{verbatim*}
  something
\end{verbatim*}
```

Perhaps a new icon for code listings that highlights whitespace?